# Write sql query

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains the below data
[image]

I want to write a query that display the below data
[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Please add to your question your code so far, even if it is broken.  Is there a particular part that is confusing you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a self join:

```
SELECT eng.id, eng.description english,
  fre.description 
FROM label eng JOIN label fre ON eng.id = fre.id
WHERE eng.languageId = 1 and fre.languageId= 2
```

As you didn't give a table name I choose `label` replace it with your real table name.

Comment: I would prefer to use proper ANSI JOINs : `FROM label eng INNER JOIN label fre ON eng.id = fre.id WHERE eng.languageId = 1 and fre.languageId = 2` - these are both cleaner, and that's the ANSI standard